# django OperationalError

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and I want to crate models the first one work and then I want to make another and I go to the admin panel and this happen[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg8oO.png]
Can someone please help me with that[https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Da01.png] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEiX.png]

Comment: Did your run makemigration and migrate command?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post image links of your code or data. Instead, post actual snippets of code or data within your question. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use the _edit_ button below your post to edit your question.

Comment: YES I DID......

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new class model, you need to make this commands:

For create a new migration:

1 - python manage.py makemigrations

For aply this migration:

2 - python manage.py migrate

Comment: Maybe you made models in separated apps, did you tried:  python manage.py makemigrations app'sname, python manage.py migrate app'sname